# Ionic build not launching

Tags: cordova, android-studio, ionic-framework

my ionic app build successfully but not launced.Its says "unfortunately, [myapp] stopped"

command: `(ionic run android -l -c -s --debug)`

Comment: without showing your error will not help you

Comment: there is no error in CMD.it shown build success.then try to launch and hanged up.And at mobile it alert "unfortunately, [myapp] stopped"

Comment: Does it work without additional parameters -> `ionic run android`?

Comment: try to restart your device and go to developer option and then turn off all the active one in that and give **revoke debugging** option and then turn on developers option and the try once more

Comment: @MohanGopi
i have updated android skd tools(libraries).It might be the reason?

Comment: @Jammy525 so what are you getting as output